# How do I change the icon theme in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, themes, icons

I want to change my icon theme to Faenza. I tried using MyUnity, but it didn't work so well. How can I change it?

Comment: What exactly didn't work when you tried using MyUnity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change icon theme with Ubuntu Tweak.

**Install Faenza Icon Theme**

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

**Install Ubuntu Tweak:**

After installation of Faenza run following commands in terminal to install "Ubuntu Tweak".

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

**How To Change Icon Theme With Ubuntu Tweak?**

- Once installed Hit Super key (windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "ubuntu tweak" and open it.
- Go to tweak tab and click on "Themes" button.

[image]

- Hare you can easily change the icon theme

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I use `gnome-tweak-tool` to change the icons.

[image]

Fist install faenza-icon-theme

Add the repository  and update

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
```

install

```
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

Now, install `gnome-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After Installation open Gnome-Tweak-Tool to change icons,

[image]

That's all :)

Answer (score 7):

I like the Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just have to install Faenza Icon Theme the way it became described here already:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

(More about this way of [installing software via add-apt-repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20689/what-does-add-apt-repository-mean) and about [how to remove it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).)

Then start **MyUnity** [image: Install myuniy] and switch to `themes`, under `icons` select "Faenza-Ambience" if 
you use Ambience as theme. Otherwise the icons in the panel don't match, which means they are black on dark background. If you prefer the Radience theme, choose "Faenza" or "Faenza-Radience". Changes should become visible immediately:

[image: faenza and myunity]

---

If you **don't want to add a PPA** as described above you can download the zip file [on its homepage](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228).

- When the download finished, extract the file via rightclick → "Extract here".
- Open this new folder.
- Doubleclick the "INSTALL" file. When asked "Do you want to run 'INSTALL', or display its contents?" choose "Run in Terminal".
- A terminal pops up, you have to answer some questions about the install.
- When ready, start MyUnity and select the new theme.

If you prefer this way of installing and want to make Faenza Icon Theme available **for all users** on your PC, download and extract the file as described above.

- Then open a terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Switch to the Faenza folder via `cd`, i.e. `cd Downloads/faenza_icons_by_tiheum-d2v6x24/`.
- Install the theme via `sudo ./INSTALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have MyUnity program here are steps to change the icon theme with it:

- Grab the the Faenza icon package/ or any other icon package. You can get more icon themes from [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Icons/):
- These packages are normally compressed so extract the compressed file to somewhere easily accessible like your desktop.
- Copy the uncompressed folder to the `.icons` folder which is hidden by default in the home folder. To reveal the hidden folder, navigate to your home folder and press `CTRL H`

[image: see the .icons folder in my home folder]

- Place the uncompressed folder in the `.icons` folder and close the folder
- Open the dash and search for `MyUnity` application and launch it
- Click on the `themes` tab in MyUnity and select the icon theme of your choice from the list of icon themes on the right side of the dialog box

[image: MyUnity theme panel]

- Last and most important step ENJOY!!!