# What visual style is this and how do I install it?

Tags: video, youtube, style

You can find my question in the title.

The video, where I saw that visual style is the following:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=padG62OCSXg

And the only thing I am interested in, is the visual style and how I can install it.

It would be really nice, if I would get an correct answer very fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your desktop image with something like [this image](http://p1.pichost.me/i/3/1263120.jpg) and you will see that your desktop will look like in that video. The launcher color and the color for some other things are derived from your desktop wallpaper. Unity color is *chameleonic*. So you don't need to change the theme or the style:

[image: desktop]

Also, you can play with some tweaks from [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/downloads/):

[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

To install Ubuntu Tweak, run next commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

To change the icon theme see this question: [How do I change the icon theme in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136473/how-do-i-change-the-icon-theme-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I did not mean the color. I ment things like the icons in the left bar ...

Comment: @Jenne I edited my question in this sense.

Comment: Thank you, that new information was helpful :) But which way should I choose? There are some ways shown, how to edit the iconset ...