# Is it possible to change the color of Ubuntu's visual style?

Tags: unity, style

Is it possible to change the color of Ubuntu's visual style from purple to another color like silver? Is this option available in Ubuntu?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/308999/147044)- Unity color is chameleonic.

Comment: I think ultimately he's asking how to make an OSX skin for Ubuntu, in a roundabout way.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your wallpaper. The Unity Desktop imitates the change and the entire dock takes a color of the same hue.