# how to change specific icons in the unity launcher (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, icons

I would like to change some specific icons in the launcher but no matter what I try I cannot solve this issue if someone could possibly supply  step by step I would be grateful.

Comment: Which icons? Otherwise you just need to follow KasiyA's linked question. If you want to change all the icons you can [change the icon theme](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136473/how-do-i-change-the-icon-theme-in-ubuntu).

Comment: example of icons I would like to change include google chrome, gimp, Geany etc

Comment: You can just edit the icons as in [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher) - to edit the launcher files for those apps you would just need to run `cd /usr/share/applications` then `gksudo gedit geany.desktop gimp.desktop google-chrome.desktop`, then you could change the icon under `Icon=`. Or you could run `gksudo nautilus /usr/share/applications`, right-click on the launchers and change the icons.