# Ubuntu folder, files icons are gone, as well as icons in toolbar are changed

Tags: 14.04, unity, apt, package-management, icons

I tried installing some theme software but it is showing me this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

[image]

Comment: I'd uninstall it asap.

Comment: Uninstall what? OS?

Comment: Uninstall the theme software that caused your problem.

Comment: I only installed GIT, nothing else

Comment: But you said "I tried installing some theme software". GIT is not theme software. If that's what caused your problem, I was suggesting that you uninstall it.

Comment: I tried but it didn't install , see error "The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: How/where did you get the theme software that you were trying to install?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136473/how-do-i-change-the-icon-theme-in-ubuntu

Comment: Was faenza-icon-theme the one you installed? If so, you could try `sudo apt-get purge faenza-icon-theme` to remove it. Did you also install ubuntu-tweak? ubuntu-tweak is no longer supported, and is not compatible with later versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried above commands, it still says "E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall faenza-icon-theme`.

Comment: Sorry, Same error as above.

Comment: In `Software & Updates`, Ubuntu Software tab, are all of the repositories checked, and a server chosen?

Comment: Yes, It's all fine

Comment: Remove ubuntu-tweak like so `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-tweak`. Install the `unity-tweak-tool` and choose your theme, and icon theme there. Report back.

Comment: System is not letting me install anything, "E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error

Comment: Sorry no luck, I'm going to format and install new version. That seems the easiest way now. Thanks you for your answers. :)