# LibreOffice PPA in 12.04 update?

Tags: updates, libreoffice, ppa

I added **ppa:libreoffice/ppa** to my 12.04 install so I could install LO 4, and my only question is: Will LO update through the ppa by itself when a new version is out, or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Hi! I useed sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

Comment: Will do in the future, thank you for your notice!

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice will update through the added ppa by itself when a new version is available from the ppa. ppa:libreoffice/ppa has packages for Ubuntu 14.04-20.04.

Comment: Hi again! I used : sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

Comment: For more information about using `sudo add-apt-repository` take a look at this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20689/what-does-add-apt-repository-mean).